# BABEL .default is not a valid Plugin property at Object.keys.forEach.key

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I am trying to create a prod and dev webpack config with a shared common config and I am running into issues with what appears to be Babel/core when I try to run `compile` and `build` commands. What is interesting is when I run `webpack` it compiles just fines. Please see below for the error I receive when I try to run either `npm run compile` or `npm run build` (see package.json for exact commands:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: [BABEL] /Users/nigelfinley/Desktop/Projects/Final 
Project/Showcase-Playlist-Generator/src/index.js: .default is not a 
valid Plugin property at Object.keys.forEach.key 
(/Users/nigelfinley/Desktop/Projects/Final Project/Showcase-Playlist- 
Generator/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/
config/validation/plugins.js:52:56)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at validatePluginObject (/Users.../node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/validation/plugins.js:50:20)
at instantiatePlugin (/Users.../node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:209:55)
at cachedFunction (/Users.../node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/caching.js:33:19)
at loadPluginDescriptor (/Users.../node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:200:10)
at config.plugins.reduce (/Users.../node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:69:20)
at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
at recurseDescriptors (/Users.../node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:67:38)
at loadFullConfig (/Users.../node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:108:6)
at process.nextTick (/Users.../node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transform.js:28:33)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
@ multi ./src/index.js main[0]
```

See below for my package.json and webpack configurations.

package.json:

```
scripts": {
    "compile": "NODE_ENV=development webpack --config webpack.dev.js -w",
    "start": "nodemon server.js",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.prod.js -p",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0-beta.55",
    "npm": "^3.10.8",
    "querystring": "^0.2.0",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-autosuggest": "^9.3.4",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.0",
    "react-bootstrap-date-picker": "^5.1.0",
    "react-dates": "^17.2.0",
    "react-datetime": "^2.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-form": "^1.0.2",
    "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.9",
    "redis": "^2.6.5",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-immutable-state-invariant": "^2.1.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "request": "^2.79.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=8.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.0.0-beta.55",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0-beta.55",
    "eslint": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "6.10.3",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "morgan": "^1.9.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.5",
    "webpack": "^4.17.1",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.1.3",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.0",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.4",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.6.0"
  }
}
```

webpack.common.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './src/index.js',
    ],
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    cache: true,
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                  loader: 'babel-loader',
                  options: {
                    presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
                    plugins: [require('@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties')]
                  }
                }
              },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                    limit: 25000
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: 'json-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]'
                }
            }
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    node: {
        console: true,
        fs: 'empty',
        net: 'empty',
        tls: 'empty'
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 8080,
        hot: true,
        proxy: {
            '/': {
                target: 'http://localhost:8888',
                secure: false,
                prependPath: false
            }
        },
        contentBase: [path.join(__dirname, '/src/assets'), path.join(__dirname, '/public')],
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
        historyApiFallback: true
    }
};
```

webpack.dev.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.config.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('development'),
            },
        }),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    ],
});
```

webpack.prod.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.config.js');
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = merge(common, {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    mode: 'production',
    cache: false,
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                // Useful to reduce the size of client-side libraries, e.g. react
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production'),
            },
        }),
        new UglifyJSPlugin({
            sourceMap: true
        }),
    ]
});
```

Any ideas or thoughts on why this is happening?

Comment: Post index.js too please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
plugins: [require('@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties')]
```

should be

```
plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']
```

or

```
plugins: [require('@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties').default]
```

otherwise Babel will not be able to process it properly when configured via a Webpack config.